# Need to FillNa with a value from a different column on the same index

Tags: python, pandas

My last line is the issue. What I'm trying to do is `fillna` in 'New Hire' with the 'New Hire' value on the same index as 'Trainer' and the 'Trainer' value needs to be included in one of the strings in `Words`.

df:

```
   Trainer New_Hire
0  Trainer1    Hire1
1  Trainer2    Hire2
2  Trainer3    Hire3
3  Trainer4      NaN
```

desired df:

```
    Trainer New_Hire
0  Trainer1    Hire1
2  Trainer3    Hire3
3  Trainer4    Hire2
```

Current Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Trainer': ['Trainer1','Trainer2','Trainer3','Trainer4'], 
'New_Hire':['Hire1','Hire2','Hire3', 0]})

words = ['Hi, Trainer2', 'Hello Bob!', 'Bonjour, Fransico']

for trainer in df['Trainer']:
    for word in words:
        if trainer in word:
            df['New_Hire'].fillna(?))
```

Comment: Please clarify your statement ". What I'm trying to do is fillna in 'New Hire' with the 'New Hire' value on the same index as 'Trainer' and the 'Trainer' value needs to be included in one of the strings in Words."  This doesn't make sense.  Why do you select 'Hire2" to be used for 'Trainer4"?  What is the logic you are employing?

Comment: i have a group of employees(trainers) i have another group being trained (new hires) if a trainer unexpectedly misses work, i need the next available trainer(trainer 4) to take the place of the trainer that called in(trainer2) and train the new hire(hire2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear as to what logic you used to arrive at your desired answer. But, I'm assuming that you want the NAs in *New_Hire* to be replaced with the *New_Hire* values whose Trainer values are present in *words*. And, you want the rows containing those Trainer values to be removed from the dataframe. Also, I'm assuming that only one Trainer value can appear in words. Based on that here's how I would go about it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Note: You cannot replace 0 using fillna, hence using np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'Trainer': ['Trainer1','Trainer2','Trainer3','Trainer4'], 
                   'New_Hire':['Hire1','Hire2','Hire3', np.nan]})

words = ['Hi, Trainer2', 'Hello Bob!', 'Bonjour, Fransico']

# Separate the words and flatten the list
ext_words = [word.split() for word in words]
flat_words = [w for word in ext_words for w in word]

# Extract replacement value
replace_val = df.loc[df['Trainer'].isin(flat_words), 'New_Hire'].values[0]

# Fill NAs with replacement value and remove the rows that match condition
df['New_Hire'].fillna(replace_val, inplace=True)
df = df.loc[~ df['Trainer'].isin(flat_words)]
print(df)
```

This would give:

```
    Trainer New_Hire
0  Trainer1    Hire1
2  Trainer3    Hire3
3  Trainer4    Hire2
```

Comment: This works. Sorry my request wasn't more clear, but you did exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.